# Group SKUs together based on similarity in PRICE

Tags: python, pandas

```
SKU_NUM       GEO_CD    GROUP_ID    PRICE   EXPECTED_OUTPUT
70907334        SV      1198094     0.84        5
70073557        SV      1198094     1.08        1
70073797        SV      1198094     1.20        1
70394170        SV      1198094     1.20        1
70395532        SV      1198094     1.20        1
70325533        SV      1198094     1.32        1
70393532        SV      1198094     1.38        4
70428444        CR      1198094     8.07        1
70428459        CR      1198094     8.07        1
70428536        CR      1198094     8.07        1
70424536        CR      1198094     7.97        1
70221536        CR      1198094     7.97        1
70428532        CR      1198094     7.52        2
70009265        CR      1198094     8.85        1
70009266        CR      1198094     8.85        1
70079602        CR      1198094     8.85        1
70079853        CR      1198094     8.85        1
70340656        CR      1198094     8.85        1
70340665        CR      1198094     8.85        1
70340325        CR      1198094     9.74        1
70343265        CR      1198094     10.18       3
70320665        CR      1198094     9.56        1
70548879        NI      1198094     23.81       6
70548879        NI      1198094     26.78       1
70271547        NI      1198094     29.76       1
70271547        NI      1198094     29.76       1
70271547        NI      1198094     32.74       1
70271547        NI      1198094     35.71       7
```

I am trying to group together SKUs with similar prices(+-10% of mode). Each GEO_CD has its own MODE, and so if the PRICE of an SKU lies within the +-10% range of the MODE, I'd like to group them together and assign them to the group EXPECTED_OUTPUT = 1, if not assign them any other number. Similarly, across all GEO_CD if the SKUs price lies within +-10% of their respective MODE, I'd assign them to group 1, and if not put them into any other group but 1.

I'd appreciate if someone can show me a way to handle this without for loops and multiple if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, I've taken the mode of PRICE:

```
mode = float(df['PRICE'].mode())
df['within_mode'] = abs((df['PRICE'] - mode)*100/df['PRICE']) < 10
df['EXPECTED_OUTPUT'] = np.where(df['within_mode']==True, 1, 0)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     SKU_NUM GEO_CD  GROUP_ID  PRICE  EXPECTED_OUTPUT  within_mode
0   70907334     SV   1198094   0.84                0        False
1   70073557     SV   1198094   1.08                0        False
2   70073797     SV   1198094   1.20                0        False
3   70394170     SV   1198094   1.20                0        False
4   70395532     SV   1198094   1.20                0        False
5   70325533     SV   1198094   1.32                0        False
6   70393532     SV   1198094   1.38                0        False
7   70428444     CR   1198094   8.07                1         True
8   70428459     CR   1198094   8.07                1         True
9   70428536     CR   1198094   8.07                1         True
10  70424536     CR   1198094   7.97                0        False
11  70221536     CR   1198094   7.97                0        False
12  70428532     CR   1198094   7.52                0        False
13  70009265     CR   1198094   8.85                1         True
14  70009266     CR   1198094   8.85                1         True
15  70079602     CR   1198094   8.85                1         True
16  70079853     CR   1198094   8.85                1         True
17  70340656     CR   1198094   8.85                1         True
18  70340665     CR   1198094   8.85                1         True
19  70340325     CR   1198094   9.74                1         True
20  70343265     CR   1198094  10.18                0        False
21  70320665     CR   1198094   9.56                1         True
22  70548879     NI   1198094  23.81                0        False
23  70548879     NI   1198094  26.78                0        False
24  70271547     NI   1198094  29.76                0        False
25  70271547     NI   1198094  29.76                0        False
26  70271547     NI   1198094  32.74                0        False
27  70271547     NI   1198094  35.71                0        False
```